# How do I programmatically instantiate elements defined in XML?

Tags: android, xml

I'm working on an Android application and can't seem to figure out how to either instantiate elements that are defined in XML, or create a new element and copy *all* of a given XML element's attributes. Defining a new element's properties in code is really annoying, and I was hoping I wouldn't have to create a Java class for each new element type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.yourlayout, root);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are total three ways for get view

```
1) Using Inflater ex. View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.yourlayout, root);
2) By making a new element ex. view v = new ImageView(context)
3) By mapping it with XMl ex. findViewById(R.id.elementId)
```